# Picking an answer

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I posted [This](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10465/kitten-traumatized) question a while ago, and both answers are really good, and both worked/are working pretty well. How can I go about accepting an answer if both answers are solving my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not obligated to select either answer in any defined time line (or ever).  It has only been one week and it may be several more before you have defined which was actually the better recommendation.  Occasionally people will find that parts of two different answers where helpful and in the end they used a third solution that was a combination of two (or more) answers.  It sounds like this might be the case here.  You can write a third answer describing what worked for you and giving credit to parts of other answer you found helpful.  You can accept the 3rd answer as the 'best for you'.

There is no rush, wait and see what really was the best in the end and then do what you feel will be most helpful to others in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Up-vote both (+10 bounty each), then pick the answer you like the best (and solved your problem; +15 bounty to him) and would prefer to be at the "top" of a list of answers.  If the community finds a different answer to be better, the accumulated up votes on it will eventually bubble it above your selected answer.

In case of a tie, pick the one that has the earliest timestamp (hover over the "answered Month Day at Time" for an exact timestamp to appear in a floating tooltip if you need to).